# Firebase returns different value from program than what is in the dashboard

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

When running a Golang program every so often it returns a different value that what is on the firestore dashboard.

`readyCom := client.Collection(devices").Where("STATUS", "==", "READY").Limit(1).Documents(ctx)`

and the document that it returns has a STATUS of "InUse".  (Ive refreshed the page)

Notes: Firestore dashboard also shows "cannot retrieve documents" from the dashboard once in a while lately. Im on the blaze plan (only $.16 daily)so Im paying for the data.
I recently turned off composite indexes which I didnt even use for that collection and after making the same call it seemed to fix the issue.

Has anyone had a similar experience or know a solution?

Comment: Are you using persistence ? because it's possible that the data you're seeing in your program is being served from cache rather than being fetched from the database. And please provide a screenshot of your collection and data as without those we can't analyze further.